# How can i check if timer1 was started?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have DownloadFileCompleted event:

```
private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                span = new TimeSpan(0, (int)numericUpDown1.Value, 0);
                label21.Text = span.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
                timer3.Start();
            }
            else if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                timer3.Stop();
                label19.Visible = false;                
                bool fileok = Bad_File_Testing(combinedTemp);
                if (fileok == true)
                {
                    File1 = new Bitmap(combinedTemp);
                    bool compared = ComparingImages(File1);
                    if (compared == false)
                    {

                        DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(sf);
                        FileInfo[] fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.gif");
                        last_file = fi[fi.Length - 1].FullName;
                        string lastFileNumber = last_file.Substring(82, 6);
                        int lastNumber = int.Parse(lastFileNumber);
                        lastNumber++;
                        string newFileName = string.Format("radar{0:D6}.gif", lastNumber);
                        identicalFilesComparison = File_Utility.File_Comparison(combinedTemp, last_file);
                        if (identicalFilesComparison == false)
                        {
                            string newfile = Path.Combine(sf, newFileName);
                            File.Copy(combinedTemp, newfile);
                            LastFileIsEmpty();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Delete(combinedTemp);
                }
                File1.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

If the e is Error timer1 is stop and timer3 start.
In timer3 i'm trying to download the file again after 30 seconds.
Then in the next time it's getting to the completed event for example this time e dosen't show any errors so it's going to the second part:

```
else if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                timer3.Stop();
                label19.Visible = false;                
                bool fileok = Bad_File_Testing(combinedTemp);
                if (fileok == true)
                {
                    File1 = new Bitmap(combinedTemp);
                    bool compared = ComparingImages(File1);
                    if (compared == false)
                    {

                        DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(sf);
                        FileInfo[] fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.gif");
                        last_file = fi[fi.Length - 1].FullName;
                        string lastFileNumber = last_file.Substring(82, 6);
                        int lastNumber = int.Parse(lastFileNumber);
                        lastNumber++;
                        string newFileName = string.Format("radar{0:D6}.gif", lastNumber);
                        identicalFilesComparison = File_Utility.File_Comparison(combinedTemp, last_file);
                        if (identicalFilesComparison == false)
                        {
                            string newfile = Path.Combine(sf, newFileName);
                            File.Copy(combinedTemp, newfile);
                            LastFileIsEmpty();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Delete(combinedTemp);
                }
                File1.Dispose();
            }
```

But since in the first time there as an error and i stopped timer1 this time there is no error so i want to start timer1 but in the constructor i start timer1 anyway and it's trying to download a file first time so there might be a situation that there is no error at all and it will allways get to the second part in the completed event.

I could put in the completed event in any case timer1.Start(); the question is that if timer1 already started and didn't stop it will make any problems to start it over again each time ?

Thats why i wanted to check if timer1 already running don't start it again.

Comment: I didn't try to figure out if you actually need to check this, but if you are using [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then there is an [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property that tells you if it is currently running.

Comment: clcto you right checking if timer1 is enabled true did it. Thanks.

Comment: @yairshalvi If he did, answer your question. You should ask him to make an Answer and mark it as 'Answered'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `timer1.Enabled` value

[`bool Timer.Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

> true if the timer is currently enabled; otherwise, false. The default
>   is false